# problemas con el foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter

Buenas Tardes compañeros necesito de su gran ayuda en este problema, estoy trabajando con `CodeIgniter` lo cual estoy haciendo un reporte `PDF` utilizando la librería `fpdf`, pero el problema es que cuando genero el reporte no me muestra la primera fila de la tabla si no del segundo registro hacia abajo.

Este es el codigo de mi controlador de la función reporte

```
public function reporte(){
       $this->load->model('registros_model');
       $this->load->library('pdf');
       $registros= $this->registros_model->lvarios();

   $this->pdf = new Pdf();

// Agregamos una página

$this->fpdf->AddPage();
$this->fpdf->AliasNbPages();

// Define el alias para el número de página que se imprimirá en el pie
  $this->fpdf->SetTitle("reportes");
$this->fpdf->SetLeftMargin(15);
$this->fpdf->SetRightMargin(15);
$this->fpdf->SetFillColor(200,200,200);

$this->fpdf->SetFont('Arial','B', 8);
$this->fpdf->Cell(40,10,'Descripcion');
$this->fpdf->Cell(40,10,'Marca');
$this->fpdf->Cell(40,10,'N_Inventario');
$this->fpdf->Cell(40,10,'Serial');
$this->fpdf->Cell(40,10,'Fecha');
//$this->fpdf->Cell(40,10,'Observaciones');
//$this->fpdf->Cell(40,10, 'Usuario');


foreach ($registros as $registro) {



  $this->fpdf->SetFont('Arial','B', 8);
  $this->fpdf->Cell(40,5,$registro->descripcion,0);
  $this->fpdf->Cell(40,5,$registro->marca,0);
  $this->fpdf->Cell(40,5,$registro->n_inventario,0);
  $this->fpdf->Cell(40,5,$registro->serial,0);
  $this->fpdf->Cell(40,5,$registro->fecha,0);
  //$this->fpdf->Cell(40,5,$registro->observaciones,0);
  //$this->fpdf->Cell(40,5,$registro->usuario,0);
  //Se agrega un salto de linea
  $this->fpdf->Ln(7);
}


echo $this->fpdf->Output('Repotre.pdf','I');

}
```

Y este es mi modelo

```
 public function lvarios() 
  { 

    $this->db->select('*');
    $q= $this->db->from('varios');  
     $q = $this->db->get();
     return $q->result();
     $q->db2_free_result();

}
```

Comment: Trata de formatear mejor el código. Por otro lado, qué hace ese `$q->db2_free_result();` después del `return`?

Comment: ya resolví el problema de por que no  me mostraba la primera fila de la tabla, por que este código $this->fpdf->Ln(7); hay que ponerlo después del foreach y no al final del recorrido, tomare en cuenta tu sugerencias M.Gress.